# Using sort java script function in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Am new to react and javascript. I have 4 columns defined in my function something similar to below:

```
<div className="scrollable-table-wrapper">
                <table id="myTable" className="table">
                  <thead className="thead-light">
                    <tr>
                      <th className="cursor-pointer" onclick={sortTable(0)} width="10%">User ID</th>
                      <th className="cursor-pointer" onclick={sortTable(1)} width="30%">FN</th>
                      <th className="cursor-pointer" onclick={sortTable(2)} width="30%">LN</th>
                      <th className="cursor-pointer" onclick={sortTable(3)} width="15%">Status1</th>
                      <th className="cursor-pointer" onclick={sortTable(4)} width="15%">Status2</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr onclick="highlightRow(this)" name="userId">
                      <td>A</td>
                      <td>ABA</td>
                      <td>ADM</td>
                      <td>Act</td>
                      <td>Act</td>
                    </tr>
```

On click of the column headers, am trying to reuse the sort function which was written in javascript

```
function sortTable(n) {
        console.log("I am inside sort");
      toggleSortArrow(n);
        var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;    
        table = document.querySelector("table:not(.d-none)");
        console.log(table);
        switching = true;
        dir = "asc";       
        while (switching) {
            switching = false;
            rows = table.rows;
            console.log(table.rows);
            for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
              
                shouldSwitch = false;
          
                x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
                y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
   
                if (dir == "asc") {                                
                    if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
                    
                        shouldSwitch = true;
                        break;
                    }
                } else if (dir == "desc") {
                    if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
                  
                        shouldSwitch = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (shouldSwitch) {           
                rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
                switching = true;
              
                switchcount++;
            } else {
                if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
                    dir = "desc";
                    switching = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It errors out saying "Cannot read property 'rows' of null" since rows is coming as null from my sortTable function. Pls help

Comment: maybe wrap sortTable in a function? e.g. `onclick={() => sortTable(0)}`

Comment: I think it seems better to read the [react documents](https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html) first and then proceed. It is doubtful whether it is a react-based project.